# Ready Api - problem with databases settings

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I've a problem. I have configured the endpoint for the PREP and PROD environment.I created Functional Tests and for the PREP environment the query to the database worked. I switched to PROD and the connection does not work.
works here

[image]

[image]

My test:
[image]

I get:

[image]

I would like to connect and so that I can switch to the database depending on the environment.

Comment: Hi,

I've answered this question this morning on the SmartBear forum.